# Uniform wall thickness for a 3D print

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing

I have high quality scans of my leg, I am trying to print a 1/4" thick shell for it.  I assumed it would be something with the extrude function, but I cannot figure it out.  Anyone have a little walk through or willing to explain the steps to a complete newb?

Basically, I want the outside of my scan mesh to become the inside of my print model, with uniform thickness all around my calf and under my foot.

Many thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the extrude function, try using the Solidify modifier on the object and play with the settings.